# Create a single function change for various CSS Selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I use the function below to add CSS classes (blue, red, pink...) in a DIV `.container` from a select `#selcolor`. Is it possible to use the same function in other select tags with different IDs? In this case the classes (blue, red, pink...) would not be added to the DIV `.container` with it the variable "div_action" function would have to be modified.

```
  function select_changed() {
    jQuery('select#selcolor').each(function() {
      var selected = jQuery(this).val();
      var div_action = '.container';
      if(selected == '') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('');
      } 
      if(selected == 'blue') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('blue');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('blue');
      }
      if(selected == 'pink') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('pink');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('pink');
      };
      if(selected == 'red') {
        jQuery(div_action).addClass('red');
      } else {
        jQuery(div_action).removeClass('red');
      };
    });
  }
  $('select#selcolor').change(function() {
    select_changed();
  });

<!-- This is HTML -->

  <select name="selcolor" id="selcolor" class="form-control">
    <option value=''>Select Color</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Is this a multi select?

Comment: how about pass the id unto the function so that you can use it to any select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.currentTarget.id` is used to get the `id` of the current target. So you can use this function for other select box also.

> *Note: I have assumed the select box as a single select and simplified the code a bit.*

```
 function select_changed(id) {
   jQuery('select#'+id).each(function() {
     var selected = jQuery(this).val();
     var div_action = '.container';
     jQuery(div_action).removeClass("blue pink red");
     jQuery(div_action).addClass(selected);
   });
 }
 $('select').change(function(event) {
   select_changed(event.currentTarget.id);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **onChange** function,this is just logic you can do whatever inside you needs.

**Function:**

```
function select_changed(val) {
  var selectedValue=val;
  if(selectedValue=='blue'){
    alert("1"+selectedValue);
  }
  else if(selectedValue=='pink'){
    alert("2"+selectedValue);
  }
  else if(selectedValue=='red'){
    alert("3"+selectedValue);
  }
}
```

**html:**

```
<select name="selcolor" id="selcolor" class="form-control" onchange="select_changed(this.value)">
  <option value=''>Select Color</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```